# Calling EJB Session outside of doGet or doPost

Tags: java, session, ejb

I am having a bit of problem figuring out whether I can actually call methods of the session bean in a method that doesn't take the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse parameters ?

Having realized that the code works in doGet and doPost methods I have modified a custom made method to take the parameters of request and response, and suddenly it has started working.

My goal is to have the method working (calling session bean methods) without having a request and response in the method parameters.

However here is the code of the problematic version which grants NullPointerException on itemRegistrationSession.openConnection();

```
package web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import auction.itemRegistrationRemote;
import auction.userRegistrationRemote;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class processItem
 */
@WebServlet("/processItem")
public class processItem extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB itemRegistrationRemote itemRegistrationSession;
    @EJB userRegistrationRemote processRegistrationSession;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public processItem() {
        super();
        getCategories();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //ArrayList<String> categories = getCategories(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected ArrayList<String> getCategories() {

        System.out.println("Hello from getCategories()");
        itemRegistrationSession.openConnection();
        System.out.println("Hello2 from getCategories()");
        ArrayList<String> categories = itemRegistrationSession.getCategories();
        itemRegistrationSession.closeConnection();
        return categories;
    }
}
```

---

```
package auction;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class itemRegistration
 */
@Singleton
public class itemRegistration implements itemRegistrationRemote {

    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement prepStat;
    ResultSet resultSet;

    final String ITEM_NAME = "ITEM_NAME";
    final String CATEGORY_NAME = "CATEGORY_NAME";
    final String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
    final String ITEM_MODEL = "ITEM_MODEL";
    final String ITEM_DESCRIPTION = "ITEM_DESCRIPTION";
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public itemRegistration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void openConnection() {
        System.out.println("Openning connection for itemRegistration");
        try {
            String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println("Openning database connection - Instantiation Exception " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Openning database connection - IllegalAccessException " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Openning database connection - ClassNotFoundException " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Adrian/MyDB;upgrade=true", "adrian", "testero");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Openning database connection - SQLException " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } // End of openConnection method

    @Override
    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            prepStat.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Closing database connection - SQLException " + e.getMessage());
        }

    } // End of closeConnection method

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getCategories() {
        ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            prepStat = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CATEGORY");
            resultSet = prepStat.executeQuery();
            int i = 1;
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                categories.add(resultSet.getString(i));
                i++;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("getCategories SQLException - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return categories;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show itemRegistrationRemote code as well?

Comment: @Jakub Hr Just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the exception because by the time you call `getCategories()` the EJBs have not been injected yet.

At constructor invocation time injection hasn't occurred yet, keep in mind that the object is just being created so the container hasn't had time to inject anything, the proper way to do this is by using the [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation. From the javadoc:

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization...

so you need to move the `getCategories()` invocation to a @PostConstruct annotated method, like this:

```
@WebServlet("/processItem")
public class processItem extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB itemRegistrationRemote itemRegistrationSession;
@EJB userRegistrationRemote processRegistrationSession;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public processItem() {
    super();
}

@Postconstruct
void init() {
  getCategories();
}...
```

Comment: Great, it does the job in that context. However when i want to call the method of getCategories from other class it seems to have this injection problems even though i putted the @Postconstruct annotation above it. Any idea how I would need to handle this ? Thanks very much

Comment: You may need to load the service using JNDI if the scenario doesn't seem to fit into the dependency injection scenario.  This involves calling the JNDI lookup, the way things were done before annotations were created to make our life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the dependency inject for the

```
@EJB itemRegistrationRemote itemRegistrationSession
```

isn't working.  Trying adding a log statement showing the value of the itemRegistrationSession object to see if that member got initialized correctly.